# How can I bind a Hold/DoubleTap event of a button to a property in ViewModel

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I have a view containing a button. And i want to perform an action on **Hold** event. How can i do this in mvvm? For **Tap** event  i can Bind it to a Command property. Is it possible to do this  with same way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go with Braulio's answer - MVVM Light is what I would use, but back in the Silverlight 3 days I used custom attached properties to achieve this. See here for an example of custom attached properties: http://umairsaeed.com/2010/04/22/custom-attached-properties-in-silverlight/

You could create a custom attached property for the hold event to bind the command to and then use it like so:

```
<Border local:MyTextBoxControl.HoldEventCommand="{Binding HoldCommand}"/>
```

This is a lot of work compared with including the mvvm light toolkit in your project and then doing this:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Hold">
        <GalaSoft_MvvmLight_Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding YourCommand}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks, got it . I'll definitely  look into MVVM Light

Comment: Here is another guide how to attach Command to double-click event in MVVM https://xcalibur37.wordpress.com/2013/09/03/mvvm-creating-an-image-that-take-a-double-click-command/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it supports the command, if not you can use MVVM Light Toolkit (free and open source) behavior: EventToCommand

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i am just wondering if there is any  other solution rather than using a frame work?