# MVVM: Button Hold event command

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I want to be able to assign two different `Command` to a `Button`:

- `Click` event `Command`
- `Hold` event Command which uses `HoldTimeout` property to specify the hold duration

  ```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty HoldCommandProperty =
  DependencyProperty.Register(
          "HoldCommand",
          typeof(ICommand),
          typeof(CommandButton),
          new PropertyMetadata(null,
              CommandChanged));

  public ICommand HoldCommand
  {
      get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
      set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
  }
  ```

How to calculate the time for click & hold and where should the calculation be done? I am not sure if handling Click event is the right place if using the 'Command' property of an button.

The result XAML should look something like that:

```
<CommandButton x:Name="InputButton" 
               Command="{Binding PrimaryCommand}"
               CommandParameter="{Binding}"
               HoldCommand="{Binding SecondaryCommand}"
               HoldCommandParameters="{Binding}"
               HoldTimeout="2000"/>
```

I have read how to implement double-clicks but this is not exactly it:

- http://brianseekford.com/index.php/2010/08/31/mouse-double-click-for-wpf-in-mvvm-using-a-clean-behavior-with-command-binding/
- [How can I bind a Hold/DoubleTap event of a button to a property in ViewModel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11341951/how-can-i-bind-a-hold-doubletap-event-of-a-button-to-a-property-in-viewmodel).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create a custom control and use DispatcherTimer class to time it. You can add another boolean and command property to activate this behaviour.

the control is as follows:

```
public class SmartButton : Button
{
    private DispatcherTimer _timer;


    public int MillisecondsToWait
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(MillisecondsToWaitProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MillisecondsToWaitProperty, value); }
    }

    public DispatcherTimer Timer
    {
        get { return _timer; }
        set { _timer = value; }
    }



    public ICommand ClickAndHoldCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ClickAndHoldCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ClickAndHoldCommandProperty, value); }
    }


    public bool EnableClickHold
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(EnableClickHoldProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EnableClickHoldProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for EnableClickHold.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnableClickHoldProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EnableClickHold", typeof(bool), typeof(SmartButton), new PropertyMetadata(false));



    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for ClickAndHoldCommand.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ClickAndHoldCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("ClickAndHoldCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(SmartButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));



    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for MillisecondsToWait.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MillisecondsToWaitProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MillisecondsToWait", typeof(int), typeof(SmartButton), new PropertyMetadata(0));


    public SmartButton()
    {
        this.PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp += OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp;
        this.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown += OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown;

    }

    private void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (EnableClickHold)
        {

                bool isMouseReleaseBeforeHoldTimeout = Timer.IsEnabled;
                ResetAndRemoveTimer();
                // Consider it as a mouse click 
                if (isMouseReleaseBeforeHoldTimeout && Command != null)
                {
                    Command.Execute(CommandParameter);
                }
                e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    private void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        if (EnableClickHold)
        {
            Timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Normal, this.Dispatcher)
            {
                Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(MillisecondsToWait)
            };
            Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            Timer.IsEnabled = true;
            Timer.Start();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }

    void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(ClickAndHoldCommand != null)
        {
            this.ClickAndHoldCommand.Execute(this.CommandParameter);
        }

        ResetAndRemoveTimer();
    }

    private void ResetAndRemoveTimer()
    {
        if (Timer == null) return;
        Timer.Tick -= Timer_Tick;
        Timer.IsEnabled = false;
        Timer.Stop();
        Timer = null;
    }
}
```

The xaml of this should look like

```
 <wpfMouseClick:SmartButton x:Name="MySmartButton"
                                   Width="100"
                                   Height="50"
                                   ClickAndHoldCommand="{Binding Path=MyTestCommand,
                                                                 ElementName=MyWindow}"
                                   EnableClickHold="True"
                                   MillisecondsToWait="1000">
            Click and Hold
        </wpfMouseClick:SmartButton>
```

Comment: Thank you for your complete solution. Just one small thing is that I need to be able to use two different commands: one for Click and another for Hold.

Comment: I have added another command "ClickAndHoldCommand" to SmartButton. You should bind your command to this one and Enable the respective property.

Comment: 'EnableClickHold' is not needed as I want to be able to assign different Click command and Hold command to same button

Comment: I found out the following edit should do it:
        private void OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            bool isMouseReleaseBeforeHoldTimeout = Timer.IsEnabled;
            ResetAndRemoveTimer();

            // Consider it as a mouse click
            if (isMouseReleaseBeforeHoldTimeout)
                Command.Execute(CommandParameter);

            e.Handled = true;
        }

Comment: Did the change u made worked for u? If yes, you may edit my answer and accept it so that it may be useful for others too. :)

Comment: Yes it did. Could I edit your post which solution worked for me tomorrow? Then I could accept it as an answer.

Comment: @JPollack The answer as been edited as required ... Accept the answer if its applicable

Answer (score 3):

Look into the [RepeatButton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms746649%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) control, which fires a `Click` event repeatedly from the time you click it to the time it is released.

To expand on this, you can control the interval of `Click` events fired, and keep track of how many will execute in a given time. For example, if the `Interval` property is set to **1000**, it will fire a `Click` event every second. Keep track of how many are fired with a counter; once **5** have fired this means the user held the button down for five seconds and you can put your "Click & Hold" event logic in the `RepeatButton` `Click` event handler and then reset the counter.

Comment: Excellent idea. I am wondering how to get the click count reference if the HoldTimeout is set to 2500 ms for example?

Answer (score 1):

How about using EventTriggers and a StopWatch.

```
<UserControl xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity">
    <Button>
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseDown">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding DownCmd}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseUp">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding UpCmd}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
</UserControl>
```

This is the C#. I am using the code in a ViewModel.

```
Stopwatch _buttonHoldStopWatch;
public DelegateCommand DownCmd { get; set; }
public DelegateCommand UpCmd { get; set; }

// Delegate commands are from the Prism framework but you can switch these out to 
regular ICommands
ResetValueDownCmd = new DelegateCommand(Down);
ResetValueUpCmd = new DelegateCommand(Up);

// User pressed down
private void Down(object dayObject)
{
    _buttonHoldStopWatch.Start(); // start watch
}

// User left go of press
private void Up(object dayObject)
{
    // Did the user hold down the button for 0.5 sec
    if (_buttonHoldStopWatch.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 500)
    {
        // Do something
    }

    _buttonHoldStopWatch.Stop(); // stop watch
    _buttonHoldStopWatch.Reset(); // reset elapsed time
}
```

Comment: Yes this could work. Although, it should be in a button control thanks for the good idea.

Comment: It is a button control.